# Go back to windows?

Tags: windows, encryption

ok so heres my problem... When i installed Ubuntu i encrypted everything for security reasons but now i need to switch back to windows and i cant boot from CD or when i boot the CD in Wine it says... Windows Setup cannot find a location to store temporary installation files. To install Windows, make sure that partition on your boot disk has at least 683 megabytes (MB) of free space. Error code: 0x80070490

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Installing Windows from Wine is impossible. You will need to boot from a Windows-install CD.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your hard disk to the ntfs filesystem again. Most likely now it is ext4 (default for ubuntu installation) and it is a filesystem windows does not support.

There are two ways you can go around this. 
1) Use the ubuntu installer partitioning tool, delete all partitions (/, /boot, swap etc). Make a new single partition for the whole hard disk and make sure you write your changes to the hard disk.

Or if you had enough ubuntu:
2) Install your ubuntu hard disk as a secondary disk in an operational windows pc. Go to control panel / administrative tools / computer managment. Navigate to Disk Managment find your ubuntu hard disk, delete the partitions, create a new one and format it.

Comment: I'm new to Linux and i don't know how to do any of that...